# Installing custom fonts on Scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

I for my project require to install a custom font for my program but cannot find the directory to install a new font. Where would I find it?

I have looked everywhere including the recycle bin

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are referring to Scratch 2, as Scratch 1.4 supports all fonts that are on your computer:

You cannot install a custom font into the Scratch 2 editor. However, you can do the next best thing; import the text. If you need the font in Vector mode (you probably should), you can use an SVG editor such as [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to import the text with 100% quality, as if you *had* imported the font.

1. Make the text using the font tool. The positioning doesn't matter, we'll do that later.
2. Select the text.
3. Convert it to a path. In [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), click on Path -> Object to Path or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to do this. Other vector editors <s>might</s> will be different.
4. Save as SVG.
5. In Scratch, import the SVG file as a costume, or into an existing costume.
6. Move it into position, as you would any other text.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install a custom font into the Scratch editor. You'll need to use some graphic software like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) to make the words you need, then import the images.